# Clojure code parser

Tags: parsing, clojure

Sorry for a "my google skills suck" question...

I'm writing a utility that calculates trends for a project to see if we meet coding standards and if we improve over time. As a learning experience I'd like to add support for Clojure. But before I invent any wheels, are there any existing libraries that can answers questions like:

- what namespaces do the file depend on
- number of lines used in a function
- number of function calls in function

or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/aphyr/meitner I think number of lines will be tricky.

Comment: For LISPs, I would try using AST depth instead of the number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

[The Clojure Toolbox](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/) lists [kibit](https://github.com/jonase/kibit) under *Code Analysis*. I haven't tried it myself, but it seems like it can scan Clojure code to find certain patterns of bad usage, and it allows you to create your own patterns.

If nothing works and find yourself forced to implement it yourself, you can at least use [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) to parse the Clojure source code into something you can use more easily.

As a sidenote - Clojure is a lisp, so checking for "*number of lines used in a function*" and "*number of function calls in function*" makes very little sense.